# No power but battery, alternator, and connection are good

Tags: electrical, starting, chevrolet, power, truck

This involves a company truck, 08 Chevy Silverado. I am not a mechanic or DIY nor do I play one on TV. The problem I am having is that every 2 or 3 months this truck will not start and completely looses power until it sits for several hours then will crank as if there was not a problem. We replaced the battery after the first time thinking this was the issue and worked fine for about 3 months then the problem occurred again. We tested the new battery (meter test and cell test) which tested like a new battery should. The alternator also showed that it was charging the battery. All of the connections are clean of corrosion and tight. All of the fuses are good. This has been on going for about 10 months now and with the latest episode, we brought it to the local dealership service department. They were able to repeat the problem but unable to determine what is causing the problem.

There are signs that this is about happen such as a couple of days before the truck may hesitate just slightly before cranking. Next sign is as soon as someone turns the key off the radio and lights that usually stay on until you open the door goes off and the truck may not crank on the first try after this incident. This last one usually means that a few cranks later that it will not start and has totally lost power.

The normal culprits for power issues seem to be working properly. Any suggestions on what the problem could be? Could this be a computer or sensor problem?

Comment: This sounds like a connection problem, either at the battery terminal, or the body ground. It could be some kind of corrosion at the body ground, which would work most of the time, yet once in a while if it gets jostled just right, would cause it to lose connection. This is a gut check, as I have no idea how electricity could then find it's way to ground afterward. I take it you lose all power when it does this (after you turn the truck off, there's no power upon turning the key back to the on position)?

Comment: Does the truck have a 6.0? if so check the grounds behind the valve covers these are problem spots.

Comment: Correct, there is no power when turning the key to the on position. And like I mentioned previously, after several hours I am able to start the truck.

Comment: Bad battery cable or connection at the other end of the battery cables.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the site won't let me add comments . I have a firend that had a similar problem with his 06 it turned out to be the control module that turns off the battery if the door is left open he ended up putting a switch on the battery, opening the switch and closing reset the system. This was easier than pulling the battery cable and cheaper than replacing the computer.
If you pull the battery cable and put it back on and it will start this may be the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the grounds and fuses battery could be junk jump the starter from the battery to the starter and if it works change the fuse